# Custom element duplicates content inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have created a custom polymer1.0 element with a div structure: Header, Content, Footer.
When I use it, it's working fine, but... When I use it inside a angular-js1.4.3 ng-repeat it's duplicating the elements.

I've created [a plunker where you can see this behaviour](http://plnkr.co/edit/UZhx4V?p=preview)

So my element template is:

```html
<template> 
    <div class="slideFormHeader">Header</div>
    <hr>
    <div class="slideFormBody">
        <content></content>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="slideFormFooter">Footer</div>
</template>
```

And when I used it like this is working fine:

```html
<my-element>My Content</my-element>
```

But not when I used it inside an ng-repeat like:

```html
<my-element ng-repeat=" item in ['My Content']">{{item}}</my-element>
```

What I'm missing?

*Note: I will not consider "Do not mix AngularJS and PolymerElements" as a valid answer."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem before and [this post](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/1890) provided me with the reason why it doesn't work as well as a possible solution.

In short, it is

> ... a result of Polymer's Shady DOM implementation.

and

> ... other frameworks like Angular don't know about Shady DOM, and there
>   are some issues with composition between Angular and Polymer 1.0.

To solve the issue, all you need is a reference to [patch-dom](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/master/src/lib/experimental/patch-dom.html).

I've modifed your [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tg87N4Bi7uPab3dxJpPJ?p=preview) by including it so now your code should work fine.

---

However, in the end I didn't go with this solution. Instead of using insertion points (i.e. `<content></content>`) to allow HTML elements to be inserted, my element exposes a `content` property and makes it available through data binding (*although be aware that doing this is less flexible as you can no longer compose different elements dynamically inside of your element*).

```
<dom-module id="my-element">

<template>
  <div class="slideFormHeader">Header</div>
  <hr>
  <div class="slideFormBody">[[content]]</div>
  <hr>
  <div class="slideFormFooter">Footer</div>
  <br>
</template>

<script>
  HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
    Polymer({
      is: "my-element",
      properties: {
        content: {
          type: String,
          value: ''
        }
      }
    });
  });
</script>
</dom-module>

<my-element ng-repeat="item in items" content="{{item}}"></my-element>
```

Here's another [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cqkogjIK724YfRYDByIv?p=preview) to deomostrate this.